# How to prove that closed intervals contain infinitely many irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, irrational-numbers

I want to prove that there are infinitely many irrational numbers in each closed interval $[x,y]$ (where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x<y$).

Is it sufficient to prove by contradiction that there exists $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $x < r < y$? Then after the math breaks down, we know the above statement stands true?

Comment: "Then after the math breaks down". What exactly will happen to math?

Comment: A valid but rather obtuse method is to use as a starting point, the answer that I posted to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4363016/irrationals-and-density/4363024?noredirect=1).  Using the principle that between any two numbers there is an irrational number, the process can be continued indefinitely.  This demonstrates that the number of irrationals between any two real numbers is unbounded.

Comment: The statement you wrote will not be sufficient to prove the theorem. Showing that there is at least one rational does not show us that there are infinitely many irrationals. It may help, as @user2661923 mentioned, to think of the density of the irrationals in the reals.

Comment: I see thank you all, I am reading more about this in some books, but I like Basic Analysis: Introduction to Real Analysis Vol I the best so far, it's a really great open source book. Is this similar to page 28, part (ii)? the link is here: https://www.jirka.org/ra/realanal.pdf

Comment: @markvs sorry I'm still learning, I meant that when the contradiction doesn't hold.

Comment: "using the following information:": How is there any "information" contained in the notation $[x,y\in \mathbb{R} : x < y]$ ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x<y$. We want to show that there are infinitely many irrational numbers in the closed interval $[x,y]$. Since this contains the open interval $(x,y)$, it will be sufficient to show that there are infinitely many irrational numbers in $(x,y)$.

Suppose (for a contradiction) that there are only *finitely* many irrational numbers in $(x,y)$. We can enumerate these as $$x=\alpha_0<\alpha_1<\,...\,<\alpha_{n-1}<\alpha_n=y.$$ All other numbers in $(x,y)$ are rational, so $(\alpha_i,\alpha_{i+1})\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ for each $i$ (although we only need to focus on one such $i$). Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is [countable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_Countably_Infinite), we must have that $(\alpha_i,\alpha_{i+1})$ is also countable. But we also know that (non-empty) open intervals are [uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215006/show-that-all-the-intervals-in-mathbbr-are-uncountable), so we have arrived at a contradiction and have completed the proof.

On your final question, proving that there exists a rational number in $(x,y)$ will not be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

**Constructively:**

There are as many *rational* numbers as you want in $[x,y]$. Consider for instance

$$\frac{\lceil mx\rceil}m,\frac{\lceil mx\rceil+1}m,\cdots\frac{\lfloor my\rfloor}m$$ for a sufficiently large natural $m$.

Now between any two rationals, let $r,s$, there is an irrational, such as

$$r+\frac{s-r}{\sqrt2}.$$

E.g., between $e$ and $\pi$, you can construct the $42$ irrationals

$$\frac{272+\frac1{\sqrt2}}{100},\frac{273+\frac1{\sqrt2}}{100},\cdots\frac{313+\frac1{\sqrt2}}{100}$$

and many more.